# What is the number in brackets on the tab label of a sql script in VS2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

After connecting to the database with a sql source file, the tab shows the filename in the tab along with my windows user id and a number in brackets. Different script files have different values in the brackets.

What are these numbers representing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Its the SPID (basically session ID) from your session in SQL server.

If you run the sp_who2 stored proc you can see more information.

It helps with working out tracing and killing any scripts you have that are causing problems.

Comment: Aah - ok. Is it possible to turn off the display of user id and spid info? It's killing the readability of my tabs.

Comment: Yeah. It's a ridiculous "feature". It seems like a bit of debug UI that snuck out of Redmond. And if it was meant to be a true feature then it would work much better in the status bar, IMHO.

Comment: I think its probably a carry over from SSMS - you get it in the tab and in the status bar there.

Answer (score 3):

That is the SPID, which nowadays uniquely identifies your user session on the server.

If you fired up SQL profiler you could filter operations by that number.

Note that you see that same number in SQL Management Studio at the top of query windows with active connections, and also down in the lower-right corner of your VS IDE.

SPID *used* to stand for Server Process ID, but now it's User Session ID.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar shows up in SQL Server Management Studio, but it's not *always* the SPID. In my current SSMS sessions, for some reason, the number in parentheses matches the SPID for the sessions that are connected to the [master] database but none of them match for the sessions connected to other databases. The value returned from @@spid is the correct value, based on what I'm seeing in the results of sp_who2 and other monitoring tools (Idera SQLdm). The session number 76 in the example below does not currently exist.

[image: SSMS Tab Title Number in Parentheses]

Comment: That's in SSMS for SQL Server 2014.